# Oracle SQL - Rows into Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I was wondering if it is possible in to display some rows as columns in Oracle 11g.

I want to the following

```
id      language     text
--------------------------
1       english      some example
1       german       an example
2       english      test
2       german       test123
```

to be displayed like this:

```
id      english        german
---------------------------------
1       some example   an example
2       test           test123
```

I tried using `pivot` but wasn't able to figure out how to handle it correctly, since `pivot` requires an aggregate function.

Comment: That's the whole point... PIVOT itself is an aggregate function; it is often used with no aggregation (with just one value to be pivoted), and then you can use `max()` or `min()` as vkp has shown in his solution. PIVOT wasn't created for transposing tables; it was created for situations where you may have numbers (dollar amounts etc.) in the "text" column, with several rows per `id` - `language` combination, and pivoting would be used to add those numbers up, or find the average, etc. So - when you use PIVOT just to transpose a table, you still must use `max()` or `min()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have one text per language per id, you can use `max` or `min` on the text column in `pivot`.

```
select * from tablename
pivot
(max(text) for language in ('english' as ENGLISH,'german' as GERMAN))
```

EDIT: Based on OP's comment *I'm having trouble figuring out how the SELECT query works if I don't want to select everything in that case. SELECT something, text FROM tablename or similar is not working*

Remember you should select all the columns you are `pivot`ing.

```
select * from 
(select text,language,id,something from tablename) t
pivot
(max(text) for language in ('english' as ENGLISH,'german' as GERMAN))
```

Edit:
To `unpivot` use

```
select * 
from (
select * from 
(select text,language,id,something from tablename) t
pivot
(max(text) for language in ('english' as ENGLISH,'german' as GERMAN))
) p 
unpivot (text for language in (ENGLISH, GERMAN))
```

Comment: I believe this will put the column names in double-quotes. That can be avoided (if desired) by including aliases for each column in the list, in the `for language in ( ... )` clause.

Comment: you are correct (column names would be in single-quotes though without the aliases).i edited the answer.

Comment: This works, thank you. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how the `SELECT` query works if I don't want to select everything in that case. `SELECT something, text FROM tablename` or similar is not working. Could you provide an example for that as well?

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. However, I'm unable to "unpivot" the table, what am I doing wrong? `SELECT * FROM tablename
unpivot
(text for language in ('english', 'german' ))`